# Android - Gallery not showing saved file

Tags: android, gallery, mediastore

In my first activity I picks a video from `MediaStore`, the videoURI is passed to the second activity where the video is played, I can then do edits to the video in this activity and save the video.

```
directoryToStore = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyAppFolder/Downloads");
```

It works and I can see the saved video and edits and I can open the video, that works fine.

The problem is that the video is not shown in my gallery until I plug my phone back to my mac, then the video shows up.

I have tried:

```
sendBroadcast(
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                    Uri.parse(ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED)));

//and

sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
            Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

I am not sure if I should use `mediascannerconection` and how to implement it.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT-----
What I tried:

```
sendBroadcast(
       new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
       Uri.parse("file://" + mVideoUri)));
```

more detail:

```
String s = "-i" + " " + mVideoUri.toString().replace("file:///", "") + " -i " + newBackgroundBitmap.getPath() + " -filter_complex [1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw:ih[ovr][base];[ovr]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.7[ovrl];[base][ovrl]overlay[v] -map [v] -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast " + directoryToStore + "/" + mEmail.getText().toString()+".mp4";
            String[] arguments = s.split(" ");
            ExecuteFFMPEG(arguments);
```

Comment: `"file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`No not a whole directory. You should supply a path to your file only.

Comment: @greenapps thank you for the reply. Where should I implement this? Just after the video is saved?

Comment: Yes. Indeed....

Comment: `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,` No no no! ???? How do you come to use media mounted? (I only see it now).

Comment: I used a example by someone else, can you please help....?

Comment: `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=20975, uid=10425` when I use `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED`

Comment: Repeat: `How do you come to use media mounted? (` Use the first one. Looks more on what you want isn't it ;-).

Comment: what do you mean, how do I come to use?

Comment: just tried the first one, doesn't work.

Comment: Adapt your post with the actual code used.

Comment: please see edit---

Comment: Uri.parse("file://" + mVideoUri))). Does that compile? If you have already an uri in mVideoUri then why parse again? What is the type of videoUri? And how should i know what is in it? And what is the Uri.toString() of the resulting uri?

Comment: please look at my new edit, hope it gives more clarity.,

Comment: Im not in for looking at that code. Please just answer my questions and give the info i asked for.

Comment: ok question 1) it does compile but the video is still not updated in my gallery. 2.) I am looking for answers and I tried what others did. I thought I had to parse it again. 3.) `mVideoUri` was parsed from a string `mStringFilePath` that was sent from activity1 with `string = videoUri.toString(); videoPlayIntent.putExtra("videoUri", string);`

Comment: You have explained some things. Why? But you did not give the info i asked for.

Comment: ok lets try again, look at my edit (more detail), `mVideoUri` is the path of the selected video, before editing has been done to the video, so that is the path from mediaStore (the original video). I use ffmpeg to do the edits and store it to a string called `String s`, I then spit the string into arguments. Please can you be more specific with your questions.

Comment: Uri.toString is `file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/` I save it to file: `directoryToStore = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyNewApp/MyVidEdits");`

Comment: Ok... I have tried `File k = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyNewApp/MyVidEdits/a.mp4");` then I name the video a.mp4 when saving it, then it works, but the user names the video.  so I need a way to find out the name of the saved video. The problem is that the edittext is in a custom alertDialog, meaning that I call a view with a edit text in it.

Comment: That should not be a problem.

Comment: there is a problem, I cant call `mEditText` when I call it in a custom view `final EditText mEditText = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);`